# python paramiko socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, paramiko

I can't connect to my host with paramiko. It's no problem to connect throgh a shell though.

My code:

```
import socket
from paramiko import client
ssh=client.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
host=socket.gethostbyname("rumo.fritz.box") # works -> host exists
print host
ssh.connect(host,2012,"sshad","MyPassword",timeout=10)
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("ls -la")
ssh.close()
```

The error+output:

```
192.168.178.37
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rumo_suspend.py", line 20, in <module>
    ssh.connect(host,2012,"sshad","MyPassword",timeout=10)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 296, in connect
    sock.connect(addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

Connecting through a shell:

```
ssh -p 2012 sshad@rumo.fritz.box
sshad@rumo.fritz.box's password: 
Welcome to Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-031600-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: I would try to get the ip6 address, and see if you can connect to that.

Comment: Try without the `socket.gethostbyname()`. `ssh.connect()` will handle a host name.

Comment: @HåkenLid I'm just connecting to Computer in the same LAN. And the router does not support ipv6.

Comment: @mhawke That is of course what i tried first. It made no difference. I just used `socket.gethostbyname()` to make sure the error is caused by the paramiko function not by my dns conf.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue.